# How to show blog post components on click without importing all components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, blogs, netlify

I am planning to create a blog using react js. My blog posts are going to be components. Now, suppose someone clicked on a post, now onclick I want to show that post component. I know routing but for that I have to import that post but that is not possible. I can't import all the post. So is there any way to show a component on click without importing that component??
Also I am hosting my blog on Netlify. So I don't want backend. I want to build my blog in such a way that I can still host it on netlify. Netlify doesn't support any backend technology i think.

Comment: You're probably asking about https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html . Doing blog app without a router is not a good idea at all. If your hosting doesn't support HTML5 routing, use hash routes.

Comment: for using router i will need to import the component in react.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The question isn't specific enough. Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do and why exactly a router creates a problem. A router can be used on static website, why is your case different? Any way, it's either a router or async component.

Comment: in my home page there will be a lot of post link. now my posts are going to be react components. each post is going to be a component. now in router we import the component first then we link to it. but you see in my home page there will be many posts. in that case i have to import all the post to make sure users when click on a post they get that component

Comment: Depends how you treat your posts, post component could load data from JSON file. If the problem is that you don't want to load all route components at once, Vue router supports lazy loading.